# Need to get Particular word using java Regex

Tags: java, regex, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to get one particular word using regex in java. thanks

in the below paragraph, I need to find the network interface name

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic_LinuxVMCent-nhi" {
name = "nic_LinuxVMCent-nhi"
location = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
ip_configuration {
name = "pubIP_LinuxVMCent-nhi"
subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.sub_wind12VM-PtN.id
private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.pubIP_LinuxVMCent-nhi.id
}
}
data "azurerm_snapshot" "snapLinuxVMCent-nhi" {
name = "CentOS76New-0"
resource_group_name = "SaaSworkloadsnaps"
}
```

Expected Result Ex:

> nic_LinuxVMCent-nhi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a multi-line bit of text. However, there appears to be a line which you could recognise with a regex:

`resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic_LinuxVMCent-nhi" {`

So the regex for that would be `^resource "azurerm_network_interface" "([^"]+)" {$` - see https://regexr.com/67ldb

You can use `Matcher.match` to see if the any line matches this expression and if it does then `matcher.group(1)` will be the value you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this regex to find the network interface name:

```
(?<=resource \"azurerm_network_interface\" \").+(?=\" {)
```

I have used lookahead to find the name.
Also, here's a link to regex101:
[Link](https://regex101.com/r/NuiKSA/1)

I don't know network interfaces so,
This regex solution is specific to "azurerm_network_interface."
If you need any additional help, please comment down below.
Cheers :)